# PubNub webrtc only working on local network

Tags: javascript, webrtc, pubnub, stun, turn

Ive asked a question about this before but without any luck..
Im having problems following this tutorial https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-21-building-a-webrtc-video-and-voice-chat-application/ .
Ive written the code and it works flawlessly on local network, but when i try to connect with a remote client(i.e. not on the same network) the code doesnt work anymore. It just shows a black screen where the video from the client should be.

```
phone.receive(function(session){
    session.connected(function(session){
        $("#vid-box").append(session.video); //outputs black screen
    });

    session.ended(function(session) {alert("Call ended: "+session.number});
});
```

Ive even contacted PubNub but they were unable to help.
Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## WebRTC Double NAT Oh no!

> ⚠️ **TURN Server *NOT PROVIDED*** ⚠️

Make sure you are not on NAT network forwarding.  Otherwise you'll need **`TURN servers`** (not provided).  TURN Servers broker network traffic and allow constrained network video conversations.  Most mobile providers are basic open routing (non-NAT).  Most corporate firewalls have at least one NAT.

- **TURN** Streams BINARY VIDEO. *Needed for NATed networks but not required.*
- **STUN** Resolves IP Address. *Peer to Peer discovery.*
- **PUBNUB** Sends IP Address.

[image: WebRTC]

> STUN provides the IP Address. There is nothing in WebRTC to provide a means to exchange that IP Address between the connecting clients. This is where PubNub comes in.

[image: STURN versus TURN server WebRTC]

### WebRTC Resources and SDK Links

- Download: [ZIP Download WebRTC SDK](https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/archive/gh-pages.zip)
- GitHub: [GitHub Repository for WebRTC SDK](https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/)
- Documentation: [GitHub WebRTC Documentation](https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/blob/gh-pages/README.md)
- Video: [What is WebRTC Video Introduction](https://vimeo.com/108532169)
- Demo: [WebRTC Live Calling App Demo](http://stephenlb.github.io/webrtc-sdk/)

Comment: For further details about PubNub and video streaming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573057/pubnub-webrtc-only-working-on-local-network/38574637#38574637 - at the end of the article at that link is a WebRTC deployment guide (nothing to do with PubNub): http://www.frafos.com/resources/white-papers/webrtc-deployment-technology/ - and I find this article from HTML5Rocks very informative: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Answer (score 2):

So, iv'e finally managed to make it work.
i simply added Turn/Stun servers to the pubnub call function, following the tutorial mentioned here: https://xirsys.com/pubnub-part-2/
Thanks alot @PubNub for your suggestion.

```
function get_xirsys_servers() {
    var servers;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/getIceServers',
        data: {
            room: 'default',
            application: 'default',
            domain: 'www.thedomainyoucreated.com',
            ident: 'yourxirsysident',
            secret: 'secret-token-from-xirsys-dash',
        },
        success: function(res) {
            res = JSON.parse(res);
            if (!res.e) servers = res.d.iceServers;
        },
        async: false
    });
    return servers;
}

//Request to connect to Remote User
function makeCall( remoteId ){
    if (!window.phone) alert("Login First!");
    else if( !remoteId ) alert("The call id is missing or invalid!");
    else phone.dial( remoteId, get_xirsys_servers() );
}
```